# STARTUP command fails : Why is that?

Tags: windows, oracle, rdbms

I just installed [Oracle Database Express Edition 11g Release 2](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/express-edition/overview/index.html).This is the first time I am using `Oracle`. Earlier I have used `MySql` and `MSSql` and I bet this one is a lot different !

These are the things I see in the `start menu` :

[image]

To start the oracle database, I click `start database`. Then in the prompt I do :

```
C:\Windows\system32>SQLPLUS / AS SYSDBA

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Sat Mar 2 20:37:14 2013

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production

SQL> STARTUP
ORA-01081: cannot start already-running ORACLE - shut it down first
SQL>
```

I did exactly the same as [written in DOCS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/server.112/e18804/startup.htm) but then why does I see that message as I run the command `STARTUP`.

Also certain commands like :

- show databases;
- use database db_name;

don't work in it ! Why is that ?

And isn't there a graphical query browser that comes packed with this RDMS ?

Comment: Your DB is already up. By default it automatically runs when Windows starts. SQL Developer (graphical query browser) is part of Oracle client.

Comment: I need to download and install it separately ?

Comment: [Yes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html)

Comment: SQL Developer is part of the Oracle 11g installation. No need to download it seperatel - although the one to download might be newer than the one that came with Oracle itself.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I have searched and do not see `SQL Developer` anywhere. Only the tools shown in the snapshot are there

Answer (score 1):

To restart Oracle, connect via SQL-PLUS as SYSDBA as you did previously, and type in the commands

```
shutdown normal;
startup mount;
alter database open;
exit;
```

[Oracle SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html) can help you graphically administer the Oracle Database.

Most Oracle metadata are stored in special tables. For example,

- To show all tables: **select * from cat;**
- To show all users/schemas: **select * from dab_users;**
- To change schemas: **alter session set current_schema=NEW_SCHEMA_NAME;**

Are there any other specific Oracle commands you were looking for?

Answer (score 1):

The message indicates the instance is already running.

On Windows check the services to see if Oracle is running

In SQL Plus you can also

```
select status from v$instance;
```

to find the status of the Oracle instance.

In your case it would have shown

```
STATUS
--------
OPEN
```

When you first connect using sql plus and the instance is not running you will see

```
SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.3.0 Production on Wed Apr 10 11:40:02 2013

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

SQL> conn /as sysdba
Connected to an idle instance.
SQL>
```

Connected to an idle instance indicates that the instance you just connected to is not running and you startup the instance and database.

Answer (score 0):

`show databases` or the `use` command are not valid for Oracle.

Please read the manual. All valid statements are documented there: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/toc.htm

As for the "graphical" SQL Tool: SQL Developer is already part of your Oracle installation. It is usually located in `ORACLE_HOME\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\sqldeveloper`. The exact path depends on the version, the edition and the installation options (the `dbhome_1` is probably different on your computer, but under `11.2.0` there should be only a single directory)

There also should be an entry in the Windows Start Menu's Oracle folder for SQL Developer. Possible something like "Development tools".

Comment: There isn't an entry of that type.

Comment: @saplingPro: That's strange. Did you search the *start menu* for sql developer? Anyways, you can download it from the Oracl website: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html

Comment: yeah I searched